# What to return when a string function fails?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Many of the applications I develop tap into the databases of pre-existing applications (I develop largely for small businesses that are trying to expand cheaply); A lot of this kind of work involves grabbing information out of other applications' databases (for example "site name", etc).
I normally have class libraries to do this kind of work, saving on database calls where possible. For example I might have a function like the below:

```
Private Function GetSiteName(ByVal dbPath As String) As String
    Dim returned As String
    Dim conn As New AdsConnection("data source = " & Path & "; ServerType=remote|local; TableType=CDX")
    Dim cmd As AdsCommand

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "select stSiteName from Sites;"
        returned = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        conn.Close()
        Return returned
    Catch e As AdsException
        ' write to log here
    End Try


End Function
```

(For those not familiar, in the particular example above I'm accessing a database from Advantage Database Server).
In the above example, I would get a warning saying not all code paths return a value. If I move the `Return` statement to just before the `End Function` (outside the `Try...Catch` block, I would get a warning saying the variable may not be initialised.

Is there a standard/preferred way of handling this? At the moment I generally handle by putting the error message into the returned value, then testing for it from the calling code but it feels clunky to me.

Comment: Is VB.NET lax on this? In C# those would be *errors*..

Comment: There's really no canonical answer to this. What you return depends on the context of the function.

Comment: @user2864740 Depends on whether option explicit is turned on. If not, VB.NET returns a null object in this instance.

Comment: @TiesonT. *Interesting - Yech* If they are treated as errors then some of the "preference" goes away.

Comment: This code could possibly leak a database connection.  If the exception occurs _after_ the connection is opened (e. g. during the `ExecuteScalar` call, execution will jump directly to the `Catch` block and the connection will not be closed.  You should enclose Sql operations that open a connection inside a `Using ... End Using` block to guarantee that the connection is closed/disposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you handled the exception in your function. A handled exception is transparent to the caller, i.e. code outside this function will have no way of determining whether the exception was raised. This design is only correct when your function behaves correctly even when a exception is raised (hence can be handled).

When the `catch` statement is executed, the function does not know what value to return. That is the problem. You should not catch the exception at this level. You should let the exception raise, then past it to the upper level, where you can show appropriate error messages to the user.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense, I think, as a self taught programmer, I handle exceptions too early and should let them climb up a level or two.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are facing has nothing to do with Error Handling in particular. The compiler issues a warning if a function doesn't return something on all code paths, and you can choose it ignore it, since it is not categorized as an `Error`. 
e.g. You will get the same warnings with `If...Else` if the code inside either `If` or `Else` doesn't return a value. Similarly you will get the warning in a `Select..Case` block if at least one of the `Case` blocks don't return a value.

It is however good to pay attention to what warnings the compiler issues and minimize the number of such warnings.

There are two approaches around this problem.

1. Keep multiple exit points in your function and ensure that all the exit points return some value.
2. Initialize your variable with some default value, and keep only one exit point for the function.

While it is debatable which one of the above is better, I personally like the second approach. It is better from code maintenance perspective too (when the function is too large).

For Example, you can initialize the variable with empty value or nothing to get rid of that warning.

```
Dim returned As String = String.Empty
...
Try
    ...
Catch e As AdsException
    ...
End Try
...
Return returned
```

In this example, you have 4 code paths from where the function can exit out (shown by `...` in the example above). Assume that you had 10 or 15. You get a warning if you do not set the return value on any of the code paths. The above solution solves the problem by initializing the variable at the beginning, and return it at the end. Then you need not worry which code path sets the variable and which doesn't.

Comment: This might be a correct answer, and it might not be. If returning a string is proper behaviour for the function in question, and signifies a DB-failure, then yes. Advising this without this disclaimer/rationale is not a good idea.

Comment: @MicroVirus, this is a generic answer to the OP's question: *"I would get a warning saying not all code paths return a value. If I move the Return statement to just before the End Function (outside the Try...Catch block, I would get a warning saying the variable may not be initialised."* The exception handling will obviously be as per the situation (which is not the question here).

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect my views properly.